# How to resolve androiddriver error messages?(Trying to setup automation mobile app testing using selenium eclipse oxygen and appium)

Tags: eclipse, appium

I am getting the following error:

```
package amazon;

import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

public class StartApplicationn {

        private static AndroidDriver(OVER HERE) driver=null;
        public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {

            File classpathRoot = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
            File appDir = new File(classpathRoot, "/Apps/Amazon/");
            File app = new File(appDir, "in.amazon.mShop.android.shopping.apk");

            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
            capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");
            capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Galaxy Note5");
            capabilities.setCapability("udid", "0915f95176431c05");
            capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "7.0");
            capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
            capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
            capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "in.amazon.mShop.android.shopping");
            capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.amazon.mShop.home.HomeActivity");

            driver = new AndroidDriver(AND HERE)(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(80, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            driver.quit();

    }

}
```

Both Androiddriver are underlined with a yellow line and I cant find a solution to it. 
When I run appium it says no device found although I have checked all ways and it is attached. Sometimes when I connect my phone with PDA + it says adb.exe file is running so cant connect so when I shut it down it says no device found. but list is showing in the device manager for the phone to be connected.

Mainly Why is androiddriver underlined in eclipse? I believe that is where the problem lies.

Any suggestions on what might be the problem. As I have tried alot of things but it didn't work. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of references to

```
AndroidDriver
```

Use:

```
AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>
```

The rest of your code, at a glance, looks okay.

Comment: Hi,Thanks alot. It helped along with some other things. Now i am stuck with another error. If you can help that would be great.

Comment: I'll try to help, sure.

Comment: Android device is connected perfectly but when pdanet+ is connected with my samsung galaxy phone I get an error that no connected devices are found. While individually everything works fine. If in the command prompt i run the adb devices, the device is listed there but then pdanet+ doesnt connect it says adb.exe file is interfering and you cannot connect. If you force shut down adb through task manager end task. Then pdanet+ connects but no device is found although u can see the device in the device manager.

Comment: Do you have the developer mode activated on your Android?

Comment: Yess!! I have developer mode enabled

Comment: I believe the problem is adb is running at more than one places. Any help with that. I have updated software of the mobile as well. Tried switching to connect to camera as I have been looking for a solution since yesterday all over the internet

Comment: Sorry, I suggest you post this as a new question, since it's not related to this issue.  That way others can offer you solutions who might not otherwise see it.

Comment: http://codekeen.blogspot.ca/2016/11/your-computer-is-running-adbexe-it-is.html                         this link is what is my problem but once you kill adb the device is not listed anymore.

Comment: I'd appreciate it if you'd upvote my answer and mark it as the solution, thanks.

Comment: I am not able to increase the upvote as i am new and dont have enough whatever is required. Thanks alot though